# Heroku app displays Application error after using it once or twice

Tags: heroku

I am going to provide an image of my log. Apparently, there is something in my code that is causing my application to crash on the website. I am using the MERN stack to create the website. After initial deployment, all was fine, however, after asking others to use the website, they would see, as would I, that the app would crash, and the only way to temporaily fix this, is my using heroku restart. [Here is one screenshot of my log,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZ1oq.png)  [and here is another.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOyaS.png) How do I fix this if I do not know what is breaking the website?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: `MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whiteliested. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/`—have you done this?

Comment: (I had to manually type out that entire error message because you posted your logs as an image. That's annoying, time-consuming, and error-prone. Make it as easy as possible for us to help you, e.g. by always posting code and error messages as _text_, usually in a code block. See [ask].)

Comment: My bad. I appreciate the effort on helping out though.